# How to Programatically update the media attachment in the specific version of a media item in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: media-library

I am currently trying to update a media item programmatically. Methods like `Create From File` or `Create From Stream` are removing all the versions of the media item item and restarting from Version 1. I require to update only on the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);

media.SetStream(stream, "YourFileExtension");
```

This code will not delete any previous version and is useful if you want to modify the content of the media item.